# Making a Google Maps marker show a specific div when clicked

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, show-hide

I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm learning as I go along, so sorry if this is simple.

What I have is a bunch of markers displaying on the map, these are loaded from an array and displayed with a function. What I want to do is make a specific div pop up which is related to the marker that was clicked on. When another marker is clicked, that previous div closes and the new div opens up.

[This is what I have so far](http://brunchtoronto.com/indexA.html), to get a concept of what I'm doing.

I imagine I would want to write a function that says... "If 'Marker A' is clicked, open up 'div A' and if 'Marker B' is clicked while 'Marker A' is open, then close 'Div A' and open up 'Div B'.

Here's my javascript.

```
 var markers = [
['Saving Grace', 43.652659,-79.412284],
['Starving Artist', 43.660281,-79.443570]
];

  // Standard google maps function
    function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.655826,-79.383116);
    var image = 'http://www.brunchtoronto.com/images/marker-blue.png';
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


    // Current Toggle function which displays Feature Box when marker is clicked
    function opendiv() {
        var ele = document.getElementById("div-feature");
                    ele.style.display = "block";                            
            } 


    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;


    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            opendiv();
            }   
        })(marker, i));
    }



}
```

And my HTML

```
<!-- Featued Window -->

    <div class="featured_window" id="div-feature" style="display: none">

                Stuff to display

    </div>

<!-- Saving Grace -->

    <div class="featured_window" id="div-sg" style="display: none">

        Stuff to display

    </div>
```

Comment: Where do you have information about your markers? What is the link between your map marker and the information you want to display? You probably want to pass your marker Id to your openDiv function and display the appropriate information from there, depending on which marker was clicked. Use the same div - just update its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a relation between the marker and the div, currently there isn't any.

Instead of an ID like `div-sg` this could be e.g. `div0` , where the number indicates the index of the marker.

Then it's no problem to access the div:

```
   //access the node
 var content=document.getElementById('div'+i)
   //create a copy of the node
 .cloneNode(true);
   //remove the id to avoid conflicts
 content.removeAttribute('id');
   //make it visible  
 content.style.display='block';
   //apply the content  and open the infoWindow 
 infowindow.setContent(content);
 infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense! I can now make them open and close the proper divs. The problem I am having is creating a statement the tells the divs I opened to close when another marker is clicked, and instead open up the new corresponding marker. Any insight on that?

Comment: I don't no your current code, but when you use the code posted by me in http://brunchtoronto.com/indexA.html there is no need for a further statement. There is only 1 infoWindow and when it is open and you click another marker it will be opened again with updated content and position.

Comment: Right, but I want the outside DIV's to act just like the infoWindows do, in that when you click another marker, the current DIV hides, and the new DIV shows up. 

Your code works perfectly, the only thing it doesn't do is HIDE the current DIV that is open when a new marker is clicked. Where do I include content.style.display='none';?

Comment: Craig Morrison: if you need to just update your div which is outside map. just update your div with infowindow content.