# Trying to get infowindow content on marker click - google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm hoping to get the html from the `infowindow` of a Google maps marker when a user clicks that marker. I want to display the `infowindow` in a div at the side - something I had no trouble doing in Fusiontables, but these are not fusiontables layers, just simple markers.

This is what I put in the loop to add markers to get the infowindow html in fusiontables:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) { 
    document.getElementById("dvInfo").innerHTML = e.infoWindowHtml;
});
```

But I can't find the equivalent for a non-fusiontables marker. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: There is no equivalent for a native google.maps.Marker.  You can add a property to the marker to hold the html. You can keep the html associated with the marker in a function closure.  The best way to do it will depend on the rest of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a Google Maps marker show a specific div when clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387767/making-a-google-maps-marker-show-a-specific-div-when-clicked)